# jQuery JavaScript 1.5.1 vulnerability

Tags: jquery, javascript

I have heard that the jQuery JavaScript Library v1.5.1 is vulnerable to Cross Site scripting (xss).

I am using this version in my website. Do all websites which use version 1.5.1 have this vulnerability, or only specific websites with version 1.5.1?

Comment: As a matter of course you should be moving to later versions of jQuery as they become available.

Answer (score 0):

Some XSS vulnerabilities are reported but not for the 1.5.1 version:
http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2011-4969/. As a matter of fact, the first thing you should do is to keep your website secure by avoiding the bad practice of outputting input without proper data validation.

Comment: Thank you but how do I find my site is vulnerable?